# use javascript split function twice

Tags: javascript, split

I have the following string:

```
12.1.20.1, 81.32.68.68:50321
```

however I need to make it like this:

```
81.32.68.68
```

Could someone help me out with this?

I've already tried to use `split(",")[1]` but I also need to remove the :50321

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried splitting by ":" and getting the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the split function twice on it, you can do something like this:

```js
console.log(
  `12.1.20.1, 81.32.68.68:50321`
    .split(", ")[1]
    .split(":")[0]
);
```

This gives just the IP address out.

```
81.32.68.68
```